# Make [maven-surefire-plugin] and [surefire] synonyms

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

If you read the descriptions for [maven-surefire-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-surefire-plugin) and [surefire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surefire), you will notice they are identical:

- they both refer to the [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/), which is a Maven plugin used to unit test Java applications;
- they have identical usage guidance;
- they are used on practically the same number of questions (around 400), so a synonym would be convenient.

[maven-surefire-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-surefire-plugin) should be made the master since it is the most descriptive one, and it is the official name of the plugin. The synonym [was suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/maven-surefire-plugin/synonyms), but the number of people that could approve it is very slim, hence why it would be nice if a moderator could do it, provided the community agrees with this request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), I've synonymized both the posts in the following direction

[maven-surefire-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-surefire-plugin) ← [surefire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/surefire)

At the time of the synonymization, the tags had 488 and 303 posts respectively.